# Conditional expectation with Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, conditional-expectation

Consider real-valued random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$; and a scalar, positive constant $k$. I want to prove the following
\begin{equation}
E[1|X+Y<Z<X+Y+k]E[X^2|X+Y<Z<X+Y+k]\ge E([X|X+Y<Z<X+Y+k])^2,
\end{equation}
where $E[\cdot|\cdot]$ is the conditional expectation operator. I have two questions. First, can we say the following: 
\begin{equation}
E[1|X+Y<Z<X+Y+k]=\int_{x\in\mathcal{R}}\left[ \int_{y\in\mathcal{R}}\left[\int_{z=x+y}^{x+y+k}f_{Z|X,Y}(z|x,y)dz\right]f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy \right]f_X(x)dx ?
\end{equation}
Second, can we define an "event" as 
\begin{equation}
A=X+Y<Z<X+Y+k ?
\end{equation} 
By doing so, we need to prove that
\begin{equation}
E[1|A]E[X^2|A]\ge E([X|A])^2,
\end{equation} 
which can be shown by invoking the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Your formula with an integral is a mystery since the LHS is 1 by definition and the RHS is <1 in most situations. Indeed the way to prove this is to use $E(X|A)^2\leqslant E(X^2|A)$, which is (a case of) the **conditional** Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and does not reduce to the standard CS inequality (meaning, you need to prove it).

Comment: @Did : Thanks... I think I see your point. My main concern is for example, how to represent these type of integrals. For example, if the integrand was $xf_{Z|X,Y}(z|x,y)$ instead of $f_{Z|X,Y}(z|x,y)$, could we say that the whole integral means $E[X|X+Y<Z<X+Y+k]$?

Comment: No, that would be $E(X\mathbf 1_A)$ where $A=[X+Y<Z<X+Y+k]$, not $E(X\mid A)$, simply because $f_{Z\mid X,Y}(z\mid x,y)f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)=f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @Did: Thanks a lot! that solves my confusion... I appreciate your help.

Comment: have you solved your question?

Comment: @ConradoCosta Based on Did's comment, it turns out that I am trying to show that $E[1_{A}] E[X^2 1_A] \ge E [X 1_A]^2$. I showed this by letting $Y=1_A$ so that the assertion becomes $E[Y]E[X^2Y]\ge E[XY]^2$. This is a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. That is, let $Z=\sqrt{Y}$, $T=X \sqrt{Y}$, then $E(Z^2)E(T^2)\ge E(ZT)^2$. Do you think that this approach is right?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly right, but weren't you interested in conditional expetations? Don't you need to prove this inequality in the conditional setting?

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that I am not :) I actually thought the integral that I have above would be a conditional expectation. Apparently, it is not!